# Operand data type nvarchar(max) is invalid for subtract operator

Tags: sql-server, join, pivot, concatenation

I am trying to display a table data from database to my application. But when I am trying to pivot the query based on the requirements I am getting the below error.

> Operand data type nvarchar(max) is invalid for subtract operator.

Below are the details. Here is my original query.

```
select Currency1, Currency2,M.MonthName+'-'+YearName as Month, Price
from tbl_Currency C
inner join tbl_Month M on M.monthID = C.monthid
inner join tbl_Year Y on Y.yearid = C.yearid
where C.monthid in ('7') and C.yearid = '5'
```

Below is the output received

[image: Table data]

Below is the format required to display data.

[image: Required Table Format]

Below is the pivot query I tried for formatting the data.

```
DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(max) ,
    @month1 as NVarchar(max) ,
    @year1 as nvarchar(max),
    @io as nvarchar(max)
set @month1 = '7';
set @year1 = '2';

set @io = (STUFF((SELECT ',[' + Convert(varchar,M.MonthName+''+YearName,50)+']' from
        tbl_Currency C inner join tbl_Month M on M.monthID=C.monthid
inner join tbl_Year Y on Y.yearid=C.yearid
where C.monthid IN (@month1  ) and C.yearid IN ( @year1 ) GROUP BY M.CodeName+''+YearName  order by M.CodeName+''+YearName
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,''));

select  @sql = 'select * from (select Currency1, Currency2,((M.CodeName) + (YearName)) as Month,price from 
tbl_Currency C inner join tbl_Month M on M.monthID=C.monthid
inner join tbl_Year Y on Y.yearid=C.yearid
where C.monthid = (3) and C.yearid = (2) ) t
PIVOT (
MAX(amount)
FOR Month IN ('+@io+' )
) As pivot_table';

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql
```

Below is the output :

[image]

How can I achieve a concatenation - in the month and year to get column name as Jul-20. I tried the below query but received error - Operand data type nvarchar(max) is invalid for subtract operator

```
select  @sql = 'select * from (select Currency1, Currency2,((M.CodeName) + '-' + (YearName)) as Month,price from 
tbl_Currency C inner join tbl_Month M on M.monthID=C.monthid
inner join tbl_Year Y on Y.yearid=C.yearid
where C.monthid = (3) and C.yearid = (2) ) t
PIVOT (
MAX(amount)
FOR Month IN ('+@io+' )
) As pivot_table';
```

Sorry for the long post. Tried to explain all the steps done. Any help would be appreciated. Since I am a new user, kindly suggest I can improve the presentation if necessary.

Comment: Careful, `'[' + @Variable + ']'` isn't safe from injection. Use `QUOTENAME(@Variable)`. As for fixing your dynamic code, `PRINT`/`SELECT` the value of your `@sql` variable, you'll likely see the problem very quickly.

Comment: You need to add quotes around your `-`. Or even better, use `CONCAT()`

Comment: If you use a currently supported Sql Server version you should probably use `FORMAT`. It may be slower, but it's a lot cleaner than trying to concatenate strings. In Sql Server 2017 you can replace the XML aggregation call with `STRING_AGG`.

Comment: Tried using CONCAT() function but still the same error. As for Lamu's suggestion of printing value of @sql, the query doesn't execute.So how will I print the value. Just a basic information the sql version is 2012

Comment: Any suggestions to try ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to add double quotes around your  `-` 
like this `((M.CodeName) + '' - '' + (YearName)) AS Month`:

```
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT Currency1
        ,Currency2
        ,((M.CodeName) + '' - '' + (YearName)) AS Month
        ,price
    FROM tbl_Currency C
    INNER JOIN tbl_Month M ON M.monthID = C.monthid
    INNER JOIN tbl_Year Y ON Y.yearid = C.yearid
    WHERE C.monthid = (3)
        AND C.yearid = (2)
    ) t
PIVOT(MAX(amount) FOR Month IN (' + @io + ')) AS pivot_table
';
```